Execute powershell text script as administrator
My script takes powershell script text as argument from "above" of my program and then i have to execute these script from different user account with elevated permissions. I'm using these code to achieve these:
$Command = gc "MyPSscript.ps1" -raw
$encodedcommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($Command))
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "-noexit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -encodedcommand $encodedcomman"

it returns:
The filename or extension is too longAt line:1

As i see, base64 has limist. How can I avoid or enlarge the size of the string 32,767 characters?
Any other solutions, which can help me to execute the text as a script with advanced privileges will be good option as well

What is the full pathname of the file MyPSscript.ps1.  It may be the length of the filename is too long.  gc may be may be replacing the short filename with the full filename.

Appart from your -EncodeCommand (which easially could be decoded) issues, you will need the appropriate permissions to make changes to the system which eventually would allow you to run something un e.g. the TaskScheduler with the "highest privileges". This is how the security is guaranteed to prefent the system/users from scripts (that could have malicious intent) similar of what you trying to do here.

If your trying to hide passwords/secrets in your (base64 encoded) script, I would highly recommend agaist doing so knowing that the general approach of dealing with credentials is to avoid them and instead rely on other means to authenticate, such as certificates or Windows authentication.


It is not obvious from the error message (The filename or extension is too long), but the problem isn't related to Base64, but to the maximum length of a process command line on Windows, which is 32,766, i.e. 32kb - 1 (see this answer for details).
The workaround is to make the elevated PowerShell process read the file itself, using the
-File parameter of powershell.exe, the Windows PowerShell CLI:
# Get the script file's full  path...
$fullScriptPath = Convert-Path "MyPSscript.ps1"
# ... and pass it to the -File parameter of powershell.exe
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "-noexit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$fullScriptPath`""

Note:

Since you're launching an elevated process (run-as-admin, due to -Verb RunAs), even if you use credentials other than the current user's (which is a must if the current user isn't an administrator in principle), the process should be able to access the script file without running into permission problems related to the script's directory location.

